# Block IP range using iptables

Tags: iptables

I am trying to use in DD-WRT iptables to block an ip range
Ex: I want to block

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.105-192.168.2.110 -j DROP
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the below

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m iprange --src-range 192.168.2.105-192.168.2.110 -j DROP
```

where

> -m, --match match
>
> Specifies  a  match  to  use,  that  is, an extension module that tests for a specific property. The set of
>         matches make up the condition under which a target is invoked. Matches are evaluated first to last as spec‐
>         ified on the command line and work in short-circuit fashion, i.e. if one extension yields false, evaluation
>         will stop.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but DD-WRT did not work this command on the firewall

Comment: Yes, `iprange` is one of iptables extensions modules (kernel module `xt_iprange.ko`), which are optional: it's possible an embedded Linux distribution may have omitted some of the extensions from its kernel configuration  to minimize kernel size or simply packaged them as a separate optional package(s) to allow minimizing storage space usage.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the iptables lock on DD-WRT only works by CIDR

ex

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.100/30 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.104/29 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.112/28 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.1.128/28 -j DROP
```

A pity, but perhaps this limitation happens because my construction has little memory